# Three.js r68 on chrome shadows and uniforms failure to render mesh

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl, shader

I have a WebGL app using three.js. It has been running fine for months until today, September 7th, 2014.
It no longer runs on Chrome, however, it still continues to run on Firefox and Safari.

I have traced the problem to a specific condition.
I load objects from json files like this:

```
            loader.load("assets/Tables.json", callback_mesh, "assets/maps/", parent.texturesTable);
```

The callback_mesh function looks like this:

```
            var callback_mesh = function (result, materials, userData) {

            for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {

                if (materials[i].uniforms != undefined) {
                    materials[i].uniforms.tDiffuse.value = userData[TEXTURE_DIFFUSE];
                    materials[i].uniforms.tNormal.value = userData[TEXTURE_NORMAL];
                    materials[i].uniforms.tSpecular.value = userData[TEXTURE_SPECULAR];
                } 
            }


            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(result, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
            mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            mesh.castShadow = true;

            objects.push(mesh);
        }
```

The above code no longer runs in Chrome.
If I remove the line "mesh.receiveShadow = true", it works fine. 
If I create a new material, instead of using the materials from the json file and modifying their parameters/uniforms, I can leave the receiveShadow set to true and it works.

So the rather specific issue is when I import an object from a json file and assign the materials array that comes from the json file to the mesh as a MeshFaceMaterial and turn on receiveShadow, the object does not load and I get the following error message:

THREE.WebGLProgram: gl.getProgramInfoLog() (260,64-140): warning X3550: sampler array index must be a literal expression, forcing loop to unroll
(89,12): error X6077: texld/texldb/texldp/dsx/dsy instructions with r# as source cannot be used inside dynamic conditional 'if' blocks, dynamic conditional subroutine calls, or loop/rep with break*.

Failed to create D3D shaders.
 three.js:25545
59WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getUniformLocation: program not linked three.js:25283
21WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: getAttribLocation: program not linked

And, again, I never saw this prior to today, maybe there was a Chrome update. And it works fine under Firefox and Safari, the mesh loads with receiveShadows on and the shadows are rendered.
In the current Chrome, it works only if I turn off receiveShadows.

Anyone have this same problem or have any thoughts on what might be causing this?
Thanks.
-mat